# Is it considered good practice to use annotation @RequestMapping on class?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

Let's say we want to write a controller for working with users, that has three endpoints:

- `/users`
- `/users/{id}`
- `/users/{id}/friends`.

We can define the URI path for the method in two ways:

1. Split onto the base and specific path, and put annotations on the class (`/users`) and on the method(``. `/{id}` and `/{id}/friends`).

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {
    @GetMapping
    public Collection<User> findAll() {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public User findById(@PathVariable long id) {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/friends")
    public List<Friend>findFriendsOfUser(@PathVariable long id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

2. Define all the paths on the method (`/users`, `/users/{id}` and `/users/{id}/friends`).

```java
@RestController
public class UsersController {
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Collection<User> findAll() {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User findById(@PathVariable long id) {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}/friends")
    public List<Friend>findFriendsOfUser(@PathVariable long id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

What are the possible advantages and disadvantages of both ways? Which one is accepted by the community?

#### Motivation of the question

I strongly believe that the second option is much better because it's much easier to read and investigate code because we can see the whole path in one place. Also it's easier to find the required method if you know its path.

Comment: `@Path` and `@RequestMapping` belong to two completely different, incompatible frameworks; the former to JAX-RS and the latter to Spring MVC. If you have both in your application and think you can use both together, you're in for a long ride of figuring out why things don't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it doesn't relate to the question.
Yes, it's absolutely clear that annotations belong to different frameworks. 
If it makes the question simpler I can remove JAX-RS example from the question.
Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Regardless of framework, metadata will be used to map the request to given object and method, the question should be improved by asking for either one of the framework. Also keep in mind different framework has their own opinionated ways to deal with such use-case. Since annotations are precompiled, it wont make much difference in java, but yes there are dynamically typed runtime, where it may have performance hit depending on how compiler works.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need an answer to JAX-RS or MVC question, you should remove that part and next time please try to ask one specific question(Those are community guidelines). As whether or not you should split endpoints, if your controller works **only with one** specific model in **plural** form(User, for example) you should definitely split for shortness. But **do not** mix plural and singular ones. **/users** for **users**, **/user{id}** for **user**. Fortunately, REST is not specific to spring and you could read one of many [articles](https://medium.com/@mwaysolutions/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api-cbe81b06f291).